# Notice: Undefined index: name when posting

Tags: php, rest, post

So I'm trying to grasp the basics of how to make/use an API. So I have a bit of code that should check if the name is what is should be, then return a `1` or `0`. So here's the code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

//Set array
$status = array();


if(isset($name) || $name = "Bob"){
    $status['success'] = 1;
    echo json_encode($status);
}
else{
    $status['success'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($status);
}
```

Then I hop over to PostMan to send the POST, I do

```
http://localhost/index.php?name=Bob
```

But all I end up getting is

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in /Users/matt/Dropbox/API Server/index.php on line 3
```

Line 3 turns out to be `$name = $_POST['name'];`. Any help would be great

Comment: The error means `$_POST['name']` has not been set. Is it supposed to be? When/where do you set it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Unrelated to the issue you're having, but in your `if` statement, you need to use `$name == "Bob"` - a single `=` is for assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting the value from URL(index.php?name=Bob) it has to be

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Post is for forms with `method="post"` attribute set. You can't data from the url using `$_POST`.

Comment: if you want is to be with $_POST then the data has to be sent in Payload. Please read about PUT, POST, GET, DELETE for API